# How to double for loop every cell in jscrollpane?

Tags: java, jtable, jscrollpane, is-empty

I have a jTable inside my jscrollpane. Is there another way besides writing a function myself to get the rowcount and coloumn count. I created a jtable from a different class and I want to create a function that will double for loop every cell in the table to check if theres an empty cell. I cant get rowCount and coloumn count and access values of the cells like I normally do if it were a JTable.

```
public SetupFrame2(String name, String cost, String handOverDate, int flats, int floors ) {
    initComponents();
    //Construction of the JTABLE
    jPanel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    int rows = flats*floors;
    JTable tbl = new JTable();
    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();

    String colomnName[] = {"Floor number","Flat number","Area (sqm)","View","Vacant"};
    dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(colomnName);

    for (int count = 1; count <= rows; count++) {
    dtm.addRow( new Object[] {"", "", "","",""} );
    }
    tbl.setModel(dtm);
    tbl.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(100,250));
    tbl.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    tbl.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);

    TableColumn viewColumn = tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
    JComboBox View_comboBox = new JComboBox();
    View_comboBox.addItem("Ocean");
    View_comboBox.addItem("Skyscrappers");
    View_comboBox.addItem("Trees");
    View_comboBox.addItem("None");
    viewColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(View_comboBox));

    TableColumn VacantColumn = tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
    JComboBox Vacant_comboBox = new JComboBox();
    Vacant_comboBox.addItem("Yes");
    Vacant_comboBox.addItem("No");
    VacantColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(Vacant_comboBox));

    jPanel1.add(new JScrollPane(tbl)); //Added jtable to Jscrollpane    
}

public boolean isJTableEmpty(JScrollPane jTable) {
      //Help
```

}

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this impossible. Please let me know, any comment from someone will be helpful.